# a loop to iterate on a numpy array columns (with dimensionality of either 1D or 2D)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to write a function that gets a numpy array, INPUT, and passes it's columns, one by one to another function.
the INPUT array is either 1D or 2D (not more)
the second function expects 1D arrays as param. (len(param.shape)==1)

I've read a similar thread, where the OP wanted to sum all columns and check for other conditions...
this, probably needs another answer.

desired operation in pseudo-code:

```
def func(INPUT,a,b,...)
    for column in INPUT: #whether be a 1D or 2D
        result = another_func(column,...)
```

have tried this:
the question is how not to check dimension of INPUT array inside func:

```
if(len(INPUT.shape)==1):
    another_func(INPUT,....)
elif(len(INPUT.shape)==2):
    for c in range(INPUT.shape[1]):
        another_func(INPUT[:,c])
```

Comment: `for column in INPUT.T: ...` might work for you.  The transpose does nothing in the 1d case; in the 2d it puts the column dimension first.   Alternatively `for j in range(INPUT.shape[-1]): column=INPUT[...,J],..` to iterate by the last index.

Comment: In your `INPUT.ndim==2` case, `enumerat(INPUT)` iterates on the rows, with `c` being the row count, not the column count.  Iterating on an array iterates on the first dimension, just as it would for a nested list of lists.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, I copied the code, and edited it here
edited it to the range() as in my tried code

Comment: So if it is 1d, use it without iteration?  In that case your function looks fine.  There's nothing wrong with checking dimensions; `numpy` functions do that all time.  Look at functions like `np.atleast_2d`.  You could force the 1d to be a 1 row 2d and then loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is: in case of 1d input, transform into 1-column 2d array, then treat as 2d input.

```
def func(INPUT, a, b):
    return np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda col: another_func(col, a, b),  # function to apply
        1,  # axis along which to apply; 1 = columns
        np.reshape(np.atleast_2d(H2), (len(H), -1))  # transform 1D->2D, if necessary
    )
```

Comment: this applies the another_func to all elements of the columns, right ?
if so, it won't help me, cause the another_func expects additional parameters. (I tried to show this by ... in result = another_func(column,...) part). but realy thanks for answers

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to pass additional params